# Dockerized app succesfully deployed but times out on warm up and

Tags: python, azure, docker, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have a dockerized app which I deployed on Azure app services perfectly fine. I then made some changes to the html file, pushed the new version to dockerhub, and finally set azure to pull the latest tag. However, now the app stopped working all together. I deleted the azure resources and services and attempted to recreate them. Here is that process:

[image: creating the web app]

[image: adding docker registry]

The log stream for the container looks like this:

```
2020-01-18T20:21:10.830911857Z  * Serving Flask app "main" (lazy loading)
2020-01-18T20:21:10.834294374Z  * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-01-18 20:31:41.719 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: gdeol4/azure-ml:version-8
2020-01-18 20:31:41.837 INFO  - version-8 Pulling from xyz
2020-01-18 20:31:41.839 INFO  -  Digest: sha256:xyz
2020-01-18 20:31:41.840 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for xyz
2020-01-18 20:31:41.845 INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2020-01-18 20:31:41.858 INFO  - Starting container for site docker run -d -p 2113:80
-e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false
-e PORT=80
-e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0
-e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1

2020-01-18 20:31:42.337 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container
2020-01-18 20:35:32.524 ERROR - Container xyz for site xyz did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.1865177 sec
2020-01-18 20:35:32.525 ERROR - Container xyz didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2020-01-18 20:35:32.535 INFO  - Stoping site because it failed during startup.
```

Comment: Your app started on port 5000 but the logs say it's trying to request it on port 80.

Comment: Use WEBSITES_PORT application setting to change the port to 5000.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks a lot, I guess I was looking at it for too long and missed that.

Comment: @GauravKumar Thanks for the help! I ended up specifying the port in the python script which also worked. I will definitely keep this option in mind as well

Comment: @GurkamalDeol Hi, can you accept the answer of '4c74356b41' as the answer of this question? this will help others who meets similar question..

Answer (score 1):

in this case the solution was to use the `WEBSITES_PORT` application setting and set it to `5000` (the port used by the app to listen to requests).